# Can't mount NFS share over TCP

Tags: centos, nfs, tcp

I'm beating my head against a wall with this one. Environment is 2 x CentOS 6 64bit installs. Both NFS client and server are fully up to date as of 1 hour ago.

I've set up an NFS export on the server:

```
/opt/nfs     10.1.1.0/24(rw,sync,no_root_squash,no_all_squash)
```

AFAICT, all relevant NFS services on the server are running:

```
(2) (0 Jobs) [root@lb01-cbr01-au ~]$ service rpcbind status
rpcbind (pid  20079) is running...
(2) (0 Jobs) [root@lb01-cbr01-au ~]$ service nfslock status
rpc.statd (pid  19986) is running...
(2) (0 Jobs) [root@lb01-cbr01-au ~]$ service nfs status
rpc.svcgssd is stopped
rpc.mountd (pid 20034) is running...
nfsd (pid 20031 20030 20029 20028 20027 20026 20025 20024) is running...
(2) (0 Jobs) [root@lb01-cbr01-au ~]$
```

On the client, both rpcbind and nfslock report as running.

On the server, the output of rpcinfo for localhost looks good:

```
[root@lb01-cbr01-au ~]# rpcinfo -p localhost
   program vers proto   port  service
    100000    4   tcp    111  portmapper
    100000    3   tcp    111  portmapper
    100000    2   tcp    111  portmapper
    100000    4   udp    111  portmapper
    100000    3   udp    111  portmapper
    100000    2   udp    111  portmapper
    100024    1   udp  39893  status
    100024    1   tcp  59014  status
    100003    2   tcp   2049  nfs
    100003    3   tcp   2049  nfs
    100003    4   tcp   2049  nfs
    100227    2   tcp   2049  nfs_acl
    100227    3   tcp   2049  nfs_acl
    100003    2   udp   2049  nfs
    100003    3   udp   2049  nfs
    100003    4   udp   2049  nfs
    100227    2   udp   2049  nfs_acl
    100227    3   udp   2049  nfs_acl
    100021    1   udp  44725  nlockmgr
    100021    3   udp  44725  nlockmgr
    100021    4   udp  44725  nlockmgr
    100021    1   tcp  40736  nlockmgr
    100021    3   tcp  40736  nlockmgr
    100021    4   tcp  40736  nlockmgr
    100005    1   udp  55385  mountd
    100005    1   tcp  55481  mountd
    100005    2   udp  46027  mountd
    100005    2   tcp  59968  mountd
    100005    3   udp  45069  mountd
    100005    3   tcp  33231  mountd
[root@lb01-cbr01-au ~]#
```

Similarly, rpcinfo -p localhost on the client indicates good state:

```
   program vers proto   port  service
    100000    4   tcp    111  portmapper
    100000    3   tcp    111  portmapper
    100000    2   tcp    111  portmapper
    100000    4   udp    111  portmapper
    100000    3   udp    111  portmapper
    100000    2   udp    111  portmapper
    100024    1   udp  59519  status
    100024    1   tcp  39715  status
```

The firewall is open between the client and server - an allow rule exists for the interface on both the input and output chain on each host.

From the client, when I issue `showmount -e <server_ip>`, it hangs for 20 seconds until eventually producing the export list. Issuing `rpcinfo -p <server_ip>` it also hangs for 20 seconds until eventually returning "rpcinfo: can't contact portmapper: RPC: Remote system error - Connection timed out".

When I attempt to actually mount the export from the client, using:

```
mount -t nfs 10.1.1.33:/opt/nfs /opt/test/nfs
```

It hangs for 3m 30 seconds, returning "mount.nfs: Connection timed out".

However, if I try and mount over UDP:

```
mount -o udp -t nfs 10.1.1.33:/opt/nfs /opt/test/nfs
```

It instantly succeeds and the mount is accessible.

I haven't done anything to hosts.allow or hosts.deny (both are empty, which from my reading of man 5 hosts_access indicates access will be allowed).

What am I missing here?

Edit: SELinux is permissive on both hosts.

Comment: I didn't have the same problem as you did, but your mention of `showmount -e <server>` just helped me resolve an issue I was having in not knowing the right export to try to mount. So thank you for a well-posed, informative question!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Turns out there was a "security" feature enabled on our PowerConnect switch that took offense to NFS SYN packets with source ports < 1024 (dos-control tcpflag). Suffice it to say, disabling the feature solved the issue.

Comment: If this did actually fix it, you should click the 'accept' check on your own answer. It's not only 'OK', it's actually encouraged so that others know what worked for this scenario.

Comment: I tried that and was told I had to wait 9 hours. That was 8 hours ago. :)

Comment: Ah. I tend to forget that rule.

Comment: Same problem on the Cisco SG-200-08: http://www.viktorious.nl/2013/11/05/cisco-sg200-08-nfs/

Answer (score 0):

Although SELinux is permissive, try :
`setsebool -P nfs_export_all_rw 1`
Restart rpcbind, nfs and nfslock
And then `exportfs -a`